# How to make the header take the full width of the webpage by using display: flex; and flex-direction: column in body?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

https://codepen.io/Vedang_0411/pen/mdPdjjW

> This is my first Question on Stack Overflow. i know its a silly question but it's first time so please reply me.

```
Here is the css code only.
     *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #header{
        background-color: cyan;
        border: 1px inset black;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #header ul{
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #header a{
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    #heading{
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #left-content ul{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding-left: 20px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    #left-content a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #right-content{
        background-color: #f04e0f;
    }
```

> I want the header part i.e. the top most part of the webpage, to occupy the full width by using display: flex; and flex-direction: column property...

> I don't understand what to do, please suggest me.
> Thanks in Advance.

Comment: just remove margin: 0 auto; from #header

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `#header` with this:

```
#header{
    background-color: cyan;
    border: 1px inset black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

This way your header will fill 100% of the view width.

Comment: `width: 100vw;` will generate horizontal scroll if there is a vertical scrollbar at the right, `width: 100%;` is a better option.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply... :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `width:100%` to `#header` or removing `margin: 0 auto;` from it will do the trick.

Right now you telling that element that you want it in the centre with `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: Please tell me how to adjust left-content and right-content to 30%-70% respectively using flex-box...Because I am a bit confused using flex-box.

Comment: @VedangKavathiya `#main { display: flex; }` and then it's children `#left-content { flex-basis: 30%; }` and `#right-content { flex-basis: 70%; }`. You can use `width` instead of `flex-basis`. `flex-basis` is `width` inside element with `flex-flow: row;` and `height` in `flex-flow: column;`.